# Display a Div Only When User is Redirect To The Same Page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple problem, I have a page that have a form of "Contact Us", in the server side I'm "translating" the form into an Email message and then send it to the relevant mail box.

**The problem** is when the user submitting the form ( after filling all fields ) the server does the processing and then redirect the user to the same HTML page, so the user just see the fields that he just filled in resets ( or at lest that what he thinks ), so I need to display some message to the user notified him that the form was submitted or else I'll have a UX problem.

I like the [Bootstrap Alert](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) so that what i'm planning to do, display the Bootstrap Alert when I redirect the user back to the same page after submitting the form.

I'm working with MVC 5 (.NET).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to use `TempData`. It is available for one request.

Answer (score 1):

Just set some boolean flag in `ViewBag` and have an alert that renders only when that flag is set.